# Google-served ads on screens with replicated content, how to explain that it is my content?

Tags: react-native, admob, restriction

I have a React Native app with admob. In the app I have many views, which 2 of them are Webview, because I did not find a react native library to add the features I wanted. So I did it with HTML ,CSS and jQuery, then I hosted the pages in my server and then embedded them in the app in a Webview component.

Few months later, Google stopped advertising and I received an email which contains the same message that is displayed in my admob account: "Google-served ads on screens with replicated content".

We do not allow Google-served ads on screens:

- with embedded or copied content from others without additional commentary, curation, or otherwise adding value to that content.

I created a topic in google support, and also I submitted the app for an examination with a comment in which I explained that the embedded content is mine. There is no copyrights to worry about.

My request was rejected.

How can I solve this ? Many apps contain webviews and ads. How can I explain to Google that the content is actually mine ?

Comment: Same happened with me too for my blog website. They have disabled my adsense account by giving the same excuse mentioned by you! :-(
Did they disabled your account too? or you've just got the policy violation warning ?

Comment: Just the warning message